# when i save data in the data base i get the id and not the attribute

Tags: json, python-3.x, class, scrapy

I have parent class and some childs class and when i save the data in The data base i receive the Id of the attribute not the content of it .Here's the classes that i have:

```
class Address(object):
  def __init__(self,RealEstate_Adress=None, RealEstate_Zip_Code=None):
    self.RealEstate_Adress = RealEstate_Adress
    self.RealEstate_Zip_Code = RealEstate_Zip_Code

class Webads( object):
  def __init__(self, type=None, titre=None):
    self.Type = type
    self.Title = titre
    self.Adress = Address()
```

and here i'm making an instance for each class :

```
add = Address()
    add.RealEstate_Adress = item["RealEstate_Adress"]
    add.RealEstate_Zip_Code = item["RealEstate_zip"]
web = Webads()
    web.Title = item["RealEstate_title"]
    web.Type = item["RealEstate_type"]
    web.Adress = add
```

and here i'm saving it as json :

```
        json_to_save = json.dumps(web.__dict__, default=str)
```

but when i run it i get in the address something like this :

```
"Adress": "<__mp_main__.Address object at 0x0000013DCB13CE80>",
```

and i want it to be like this :

```
{
"Type": "Appartement",
"Title": "appartement 2 pièces",
"Adress":{
          "Realestate_Adress":"paris 15"
          "Realestate_zip_code":"75015"

          }
}
```

Comment: How would you like it to look like? Also, why do you use classes instead of e.g. dictionaries?

Comment: i want it to be like this :

Comment: {type : 'vente' , titre : 'appartement',Adresse:{realestate_Adress: '....', realestate_zip_code} }

Answer (score 0):

You could use dictionaries instead of classes:

```py
web = {
    'Title': item["RealEstate_title"],
    'Type': item["RealEstate_type"],
    'Adress': {
        'RealEstate_Adress': item["RealEstate_Adress"],
        'RealEstate_Zip_Code': item["RealEstate_zip"],
    },
}
```

Comment: it can't be with classes or what?

Comment: It can, but if your classes are simply going to contain data, dictionaries are a better approach. To stick to classes, you’ll have to either implement `YourClass.__str__()` and cast your objects to `str`, or implement `YourClass.__repr__()`.

Comment: Sorry but i didn't understand exactly can you make it in my code please if you can because i'm a beginner in python .

Comment: Then I recommend you use dictionaries. Otherwise, there are lots of resources in the internet that explain how `__repr__` and `__str__` work. For example: https://www.journaldev.com/22460/python-str-repr-functions